# File and Folder Locker

Tags: flutter, dart, file-security

I am new in flutter and just want to ask question regarding to create file/folder locker app (Password base) with flutter. My first question is that possible with flutter?
I saw a lot of apps on play store on the topic of Gallery Vault, File locker etc.
Example Apps are
[Photovault](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enchantedcloud.photovault&hl=en) and
[Photolocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.photolocker&hl=en)

I have read some documentation of dart and find out the **[FileLocker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/FileLock-class.html)** class. But don't have an idea how it will work also not found any solution on stack overflow and GitHub.

Comment: I didn't find a package for that, I think it is not possible, because you need low-level access to the system. It would be best if you considered using native development.

Comment: I know there is not a package on pub.dev for this. But dart has a class name FileLocker.  So if dart has class then it means we can deal with it. So my question is how we can use it? Because I am new in flutter.

Comment: yes, I am sorry , and I even found an app made with flutter in codecanyon , I looking for solution.